# Configure S3 bucket settings for CRUD application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CRUD application built with node/express where users can upload images to my s3 bucket. I'm wondering what the best way to configure my bucket settings is?

Currently they're set like this:

```
Block all public access
 Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
 Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
 Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
 Off
Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies
 Off
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way I can tighten the security up, is there a way I can block all those points, but whitelist my website sort of thing?

And yes I have read through the S3 documentation, and I haven't been able to find any relevant information

Comment: What does that bucket represent? Is it your hosted website assets or is it the location that users upload images to? You would not typically store both in the same S3 bucket.

Comment: @jarmod Hi thanks for the reply, and sorry for the poor explanation, I'm pretty new to aws/s3. This bucket is only for images that users upload. I'm having a really tough time finding information on how to configure buckets for a CRUD application, obviously there needs to be some public access allowed, but I'm just worried about granting to much access or missing out on security policies.

Comment: You mentioned a Node/Express app. Is this a webapp running in AWS that your clients connect to? If so, typically this webapp would have AWS permissions, through an IAM role, that allow the webapp to read/write/delete objects in the S3 bucket as needed. You wouldn't provide these permissions to the webapp through an S3 bucket policy.

Comment: @jarmod The webapp is hosted with heroku, the only thing I'm using AWS for is storing & displaying the photos that users upload

Comment: You shouldn't provide access via S3 bucket policy and, assuming you don't want any of these uploaded files to be publicly available, you should enable all the Block Public Access options. Your Heroku app should be [supplied with AWS credentials for S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) so that it can perform CRUD operations against your S3 bucket. Those credentials should be associated with permissions allowing the relevant S3 access. Note that you cannot update S3 objects, you can only replace.